# Isomorphism of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Are $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-1,y-1)$ isomorphic as $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-modules?

I think they are cyclic so they are isomorphic, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that if $M$ is a module over a ring $R$, then:
$$\mathrm{ann}(M)=\{r\in R\mid \forall_{m\in M}rm=0\}$$
This is two sided ideal of $R$ called anihilator of $M$. Now if $M_1\cong M_2$ as $R$-modules, then:
$$\mathrm{ann}(M_1)=\mathrm{ann}(M_2)$$
Annihilator of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y)$ is $(x,y)$ and annihilator of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-1,y-1)$ is $(x-1,y-1)$. These are not equal and therefore, modules in question are not isomorphic.